How to use a ros 2 topic with Gazebo rf_comms plugin
I have successfully run the given rf_comms example which sends a string message. However, I am wondering how to extend this to use data from ROS topics such as a PointCloud/Octomaps. I am using Gazebo Garden and ROS Humble in Ubuntu 22.04.
I am developing a multi robot simulation. What I want to do is to send the PointCloud/Octomaps data from one robot to another. I am adding several points/questions after some research here:

Can I use rf_comms standalone publisher to send PointCloud data from a gazebo sensor topic?
Can T use rf_comms standalone publisher to send Octomap data from ros2 topic? (I think there's an issue here as there's no ros gz bridge for Octomap msgs).
I believe another alternative would be to integrate ros2 in the gazebo publisher. Is it possible? If so, are there any examples?

